# Spacemacs - move org-mode customization to separate file

Tags: spacemacs, load-path

I have several hundred lines of customization code for org-mode in a private layer.  In Spacemacs, customization code typically goes in a function called `$LAYER/init-$PACKAGE` or in my case, `joe/post-init-org`.

However, this adds three layers of indentation and is annoying to re-eval code segments when modifying a config.

```
(defun joe/post-init-org ()
  "Init org."
  (use-package org
    :config
    (progn
      ;; Extensive list of customization...
      )))
```

Is there a proper way to do this in Spacemacs?  Or should I just do something like:

```
(defun joe/post-init-org ()
  "Init org."
  (use-package org
    :config
    (progn
      (load "~/path/to/my/file")
      )))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no 'proper' way of doing this. What I use in such cases is not `load` but `require`. Every private layer that has such configurations files (features / packages) has a folder named `extra`. And I just add that folder to load path using `add-to-load-path`. After that I use `require` to load configurations inside of `:config` just like you use `load`.

I understand that this might sound like a total overhead, but Spacemacs is about lazy loading and such approach doesn't break this principle. If you don't care about lazy loading - you can force load org and configure without any indentations.

Also, it's pretty easy to automate the step where you add `extra` folder to `load-path` using following snippet.

```
(defun d12-layers/add-extra-to-load-path (layer)
  "Add 'extra' folder to `load-path' for a given LAYER.

Load-path is modified only when such folder exists."
  (let* ((layer-path (configuration-layer/get-layer-path layer))
         (layer-root (format "%s%s/" layer-path layer))
         (extra-path (concat layer-root "extra/")))
    (when (file-exists-p extra-path)
        (add-to-load-path extra-path))))

(mapc #'d12-layers/add-extra-to-load-path (configuration-layer/get-layers-list))
```

This saves you from using layer name somewhere except of list of layers.

**Updated**

Forgot to say, how to use this. Just put declaration of `d12-layers/add-extra-to-load-path` function somewhere in `.spacemacs` or `$SPACEMACSDIR/init.el` (based on what you're using) and then place following snippet in your `dotspacemacs/user-init` function:

```
(configuration-layer//declare-layers)
(mapc #'d12-layers/add-extra-to-load-path
      (configuration-layer/get-layers-list))
```

I understand that using 'private' `configuration-layer//declare-layers` function is far from good, but it's better to setup `load-path` **before** layers are loaded, so we can `require` in `config.el` and `funcs.el`.

Comment: Nice approach.  I like that it works automatically.

Comment: Glad that you like it :) Have fun with Spacemacs!

Answer (score 0):

Below is the way set up all my customizations for layers. I am using the `.spacemacs.d` directory and the `init.el`, but this should also work fine in `.spacemacs` file. It does not separate them into their own files, but I like to keep mine all in the init file.

```
(spacemacs|use-package-add-hook org-mode
  :post-config
  (progn
      ;; custom settings follow
    ))
```

Comment: But this doesn't fix the initial problem - indentation and evaluation bizarre. As far as I understand, the problem of OP is not the layers system, but code organisation - your configs are nested. `spacemacs|use-package-add-hook` just allows to avoid creating layer for custom configuration of specific package.

Comment: @d12frosted you are correct, I misread the OP. My bad.

Comment: Don't worry :) Though `spacemacs|use-package-add-hook` is really good macro if you have to make a minor configuration for package that you don't want to configure in any of private layers.